# Enabling mutual SSL per service in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

I've already managed to successfully set up mutual SSL between a client application and a Tomcat instance. However, I'm now looking for a way to expose only a subset of service deployed in Tomcat via mutual SSL. Although it looks possible to use APR configurations (by defining the value of "SSLVerifyClient" attribute to "optional") I can't seem to find a way to do the same with the JSSE implementation of SSL in Tomcat. Appreciate any input on how this can be done.

Cheers,
Prabath

Comment: Have you considered reading the Tomcat documentation for the connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note that `SSLVerifyClient="optional"` with APR is equivalent to `clientAuth="want"` with the JSSE connector. Despite being optional, this is negotiated upon connection, not re-negotiated once the path is known by the server.)

If you want to use client-certificate authentication only for certain webapps (or paths), you need to configure the connector with a truststore, but leave `clientAuth="false"`.

Then, in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`, you need to configure `CLIENT-CERT` authentication. This will use re-negotiation to ask for a client certificate when necessary. The configuration looks like this:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>My Webapp</display-name>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>App</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>cert</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>cert</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

(You'd also need to map the user's Subject DNs to the appropriate roles, when configuring the Tomcat users.)