# Enable Tomcat clientAuth only for certain URLs

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, x509

We are creating a server side Java application running in Tomcat which has two parts.  The first part is a RESTful web service, and we want `clientAuth="true"`.  The second part is web-based, and we want `clientAuth="false"`.   The web-based portion will use login credentials alone for security.

In Tomcat, setting the `clientAuth` parameter in `server.xml` is how to control whether Tomcat enforces SSL during a client request.

My question is whether it be possible to have `clientAuth` set to `true` only for certain URL paths?

That failing, is there any way to force Tomcat to put the X509 certificate into the `ServletRequest` when `clientAuth` be set to `false`?

A question similar to this has been asked before on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962069/tomcat-client-authentication-using-clientauth-want) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937833/configure-tomcat-for-client-authentication-only-for-specific-url-patterns).

Answer (score 1):

If those two are there as separate web applications you can define two connectors and each with separate clientAuth settings. But for restricting accessing web application through web service port; you will have to do it with a load balancer or a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the belated reply.  What we ended up doing was abandoning the SSL layer and running Tomcat is unauth mode, instead passing certificates in the header.